# How to find out if a given DateTime on the day of the DST change?

Tags: c#, datetime, dst

I am iterating through different datasets, each one for another day.

**How do I find out that a given DateTime is on the day of the Daylight-Change for a specific TimeZone?**

That last part is important: Iam on another local timezone and need to find out when this change appears on another TimeZone!

I found out how to get the Delta, Start and End via the [TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule.aspx). But for e.g. Lissabon time there is no information on which day of the year the change from 02:00 to 01:00 happens.

/edit: Just found out that there some kind of information within the AdjustmentRule, but it is not easily accessible like a regular date.

**Is there a helper method that calculates the exact date for a given year?**

[image]

```
public DaylightTime GetDaylightTimeForTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo tzi)
        {
            var adj_rules = tzi.GetAdjustmentRules();
            var daylighttime = new DaylightTime(
            adj_rules[0].DateStart, adj_rules[0].DateEnd, adj_rules[0].DaylightDelta);
            return daylighttime; /* Only part of the solution 
             since it does not deliver the actual date when it happens */
        }
```

Comment: What will you *do*, specially, once you've determined the answer to this question?

Comment: If I have the day I would add it to the return value of my function so that I have an exact date and hour:min when the change happens. With this information I need to transform some timeperiods in the dataset that fall within this range

-> I just saw that there is an DaylightTransitionTimeStart member of the adjustment-rule.  The information is somehow weird. Is there anyway to get the exact date easily by providing a year?

Comment: Follow the instructions on [Converting Times Between Time Zones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert dates between time zones or apply/remove dst correctly.

Comment: Do you really need to know the date? Or just if a given date is using Daylight saving? See [TimeZoneInfo class] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and look for functions `Is*Time(...)`

Comment: I found this calculation: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63170/extension-methods-for-daylight-savings-time-dates

This is what I needed!